# How can we define a color for each line in an SVG path

Tags: svg

I'am working with a svg file to get the path of a triangles in a triangulated image using Delaunay triangulation .the paths are represented as below:

```
<path
        fill="rgba(148,148,147,255)"
        stroke="rgba(0,0,0,255)"
        d="M410,224 L411,227 L410,227 L410,224"
    />

    <path
        fill="rgba(232,232,232,255)"
        stroke="rgba(0,0,0,255)"
        d="M179,108 L180,107 L183,113 L179,108"
    />
```

I want to define a color for  each 2 values, i mean for example  the segment M179,108 L180,107 in blue and l183,113 L179,108 in red.How can I do that ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't. Create multiple paths if you want to do that. Or use separate line elements.

Comment: Sorry , but what did you mean by separate line elements ?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp

Comment: <line stroke="blue".../> <line stroke="green"../> etc etc.